# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException - while configuring Kubernetes config server into spring-boot api

Tags: serialization, jackson-databind, spring-boot-3, spring-cloud-kubernetes, fabric8-kubernetes-client

I am trying to configure spring-cloud-starter-Kubernetes-config as config server and trying to have my  springboot 3 api to act as a client to it. I have added the config into application.yml and also added the dependencies into pom.xml. But I am getting a persistent error related to Jackson databind dependency.

`Error Log:`
`03:15:50.781 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed`
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config$ExecCredential (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('kubelogin')`
`at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4449)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4390)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.KubernetesSerialization.parseYaml(KubernetesSerialization.java:276)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.KubernetesSerialization.unmarshal(KubernetesSerialization.java:252)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.KubernetesSerialization.unmarshal(KubernetesSerialization.java:342)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.KubernetesSerialization.unmarshal(KubernetesSerialization.java:327)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Serialization.unmarshal(Serialization.java:185)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.getExecCredentialFromExecConfig(Config.java:820)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.mergeKubeConfigExecCredential(Config.java:787)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.mergeKubeConfigAuthInfo(Config.java:766)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.mergeKubeConfigContents(Config.java:736)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.loadFromKubeconfig(Config.java:710)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.tryKubeConfig(Config.java:672)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.autoConfigure(Config.java:292)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.<init>(Config.java:257)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config.<init>(Config.java:248)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.ConfigBuilder.<init>(ConfigBuilder.java:6)`
`at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:37)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.profile.KubernetesProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor.isInsideKubernetes(KubernetesProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:74)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.profile.KubernetesProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(KubernetesProfileEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:52)`
`at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)`
`at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133)`
`at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)`
`at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)`
`at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)`
`at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)`
`at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:174)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:145)`
`at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133)`
`at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)`
`at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)`
`at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:354)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)`
`at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)`
`at com.jh.de.pacdetails.PacDetailsApplication.main(PacDetailsApplication.java:12)`
`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config$ExecCredential (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('kubelogin')`
`at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1733)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1358)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1500)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:197)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)`
`at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4444)`
`... 54 common frames omitted`

`Process finished with exit code 1`

I tried to exclude the Jacson libraries from Kubernetes dependencies and added the latest Jackson core dependencies but it still doesn't work.

```
Addition in pom:
```

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
Application.yml:spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: NON_NULL
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      discovery:
        enabled: false
      config:
        enabled: true
        name: pacdetails
      reload:
        enabled: true
        strategy: restart_context
    config:
      enabled: false
management:
  info:
    build:
      enabled: true
    env:
      enabled: true
    java:
      enabled: true
    os:
      enabled: true
    git:
      enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
        add-additional-paths: true
      show-details: always
      enabled: true
  health:
    db: true
    defaults:
      enabled: true
    livenessstate:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - health
          - db
          - info
```